# how we use window user phone controll in my app

Tags: windows-phone-7

i want to add a user control like stack panel in my Grid for example

- a grid which name content panel which is in MainPage.xaml
 - List item

-stack panel which is in usercontrol.xaml

```
 <UserControl x:Class="USER.WindowsPhoneControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">

        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <!--Create a Style for a TextBlock.-->
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="TextBlockStyle">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Navy"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
            </Style>

            <!--Create a Style for a TextBlock.-->
            <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="TextBoxStyle">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>

        <TextBlock FontSize="18" Text="Enter your name." Name="abc" />
        <StackPanel   Orientation="Horizontal" Name="sta">
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}">
                First Name:
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBox Name="firstName" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}">
                Last Name:
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBox Name="lastName" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"  
                     Margin="6,4,4,4"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Button Width="50" Content="Submit" Click="Button_Click"/>

    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

i want to add stack panel in grid .....

thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain what you're actually asking in your question but it's perfectly possible to put a StackPanel in a [Grid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid%28v=vs.96%29.aspx):

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel />
</Grid>
```